# Microsoft Deployment Toolkit: Missing install.wim for windows 8.1

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-8.1, mdt, wim

I'm trying to setup a windows 8.1 deployment using [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40796) but I'm having trouble importing the operating system files. The sources directory in the Windows 8.1 installation disk contains an "install.esd" file, and not an "install.wim" file. I have gathered that install.esd is an encrypted version of install.wim and the only way I have found to get the install.wim is to install the operating system on a virtual machine then capture the wim from that. Is this the correct way to get the windows 8.1 install.wim? If this is the case, then why does the documentation appear to make no mention of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `en_windows_8.1_enterprise_with_update_x64_dvd_4065178.iso` has an install.wim.

Maybe you should download a fresh copy of the install disk from Microsoft.